# Legality of battle advice to non American military

Tags: united-states, citizenship, military, mercenary

Is it legal to directly **advise or become advisor** to a military in a war in which America is neutral?

Would the act itself be punishable by loss of citizenship?

Comment: Loosely related: the UK has the [Foreign Enlistment Act 1870](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Enlistment_Act_1870), which applies to British citizens helping "any foreign state at war with any foreign state at peace with Her Majesty". Canada has the similar Foreign Enlistment Act of 1937. Prosecutions appear to be rare.

Comment: I'm not aware of *any* act which is punishable by loss of citizenship.  AFAIK the only ways to lose US citizenship are to voluntarily renounce it, or to be found to have fraudulently obtained it in the first place.

Comment: @NateEldredge: [8 USC 1481](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1481) provides a list of potentially expatriating acts, of which renunciation is one. But in all cases, it is required that the person intended to relinquish US citizenship in order to lose it.

Answer (score 3):

[18 USC 960](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/960) provides a disincentive against such actions.

> Whoever, within the United States, knowingly begins or sets on foot or
> provides or prepares a means for or furnishes the money for, or takes
> part in, any military or naval expedition or enterprise to be carried
> on from thence against the territory or dominion of any foreign prince
> or state, or of any colony, district, or people with whom the United
> States is at peace, shall be fined under this title or imprisoned not
> more than three years, or both

Also see [18 USC 959](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/959), covering enlistment. "At peace" is not statutorily defined, so it is not obvious whether the US is "at peace" with Ethiopia (Tigray war) or Russia (various offenses). A formal state of war has not existed between the US and another nation for 70 years.

Comment: Since the US has not been officially at war for 70 years but _did_ indeed fight in many places, nobody seems to care about this law. Has there ever been someone found guilty for this?

Comment: @PMF I'm quite sure so... anytime the American is helping a party in opposition to US interests.  It's weird now because most people involved in such adventurism are helping Ukraine defend their home territory (the text doesn't seem to prohibit *that* but suppose you helped develop drones that attacked logistics hubs in Russia Proper).  Be interesting from Japan's POV as they actually are at declared war with Russia.  Honestly I'm expecting them to take the Kurils back at any moment lol.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica When I understand the text correctly, it would also be punishable to support America's wars against Iraq or Afghanistan (since the US was never officially at war with them).

Comment: @PMF sounds right to me.

Comment: @PMF: I think the point is that "at peace" is *not* defined as "not in a Congressionally declared war".  There are undeclared wars which form a middle ground.  Congress explicitly authorized military action against Iraq and Afghanistan.

Comment: @user6726 Is providing advise or being advisor included in that law

Comment: "takes part in" includes advising.

Comment: "*to be carried on from thence*" refers back to "*within the United States,*" so this applies only to military activities **based** in the US, and would not apply to US citizens who travel outside the US to fight or advise. For example, th members of the Abraham Lincoln Brigade (who fought in the Spanidh civil war against Franco) were not prosecuted.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> Would the act itself be punishable by loss of citizenship?

No. This is not an activity for which U.S. citizenship can be revoked.